# Ensure equal work distribution in a group whose "composition" changes daily.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, optimization, queueing-theory

I want to ensure that incoming work is equally distributed as much as possible across a group of 100 people. I am not concerned about the complexity of each piece of work. I just want to ensure that the work is distributed equally on a numerical basis. The constraints/conditions are as follows:

1. The work week begins on a Monday and ends on a Friday.
2. Work is assigned immediately when it comes in.
3. Work is assigned only to those who are available that day.
4. A person's availability can vary from day to day.
5. We cannot predict how much work will come in each day. But the amount of work that comes in each day is independent and identically distributed.
6. At the beginning of each week, everybody's availability for each day of that week is known.

We are not too concerned about the distribution of work every day. What's of greater concern is the distribution of work at the end of each work week. At the end of each work week (i.e Friday), I want to ensure that all the incoming work has been distributed as equally as possible over the entire group of 100, taking availability over that week into account.

For example, let's assume there are three workers: two are available all week, and the third is not available at all. The work distribution should be proportional to worker availability. Thus (15, 15, 0) is the goal, not (10, 10, 10).

Is there a mathematical formula/concept that deals with such an issue? I've been trying to find an answer but I have not come across anything that addresses this issue.

Background: I do not have any advanced mathematical training/education. So, I would appreciate any help on this matter. Apologies if my tags are inaccurate as I'm really unsure what branch of mathematics deals with such an issue.

Comment: You're making too few assumptions for a tractable problem. In particular point 5 and 6 means that you know essentially nothing, and might as well assign work randomly depending on who's available. There might be some decent heuristics available, but we'd need to have much tighter constraints on the problem.

Comment: I agree with your comments. But that's the parameters of the real life issue I'm facing. Would it make a difference if constraint 6 is removed; i.e everybody's availability for each day of that week is known at the beginning of that week.

Comment: In a real life situation you will have *some* idea of the distribution of the work. E.g., you might know (or be able to make the simplification) that the work on each day is independent and identically distributed.

Comment: You also haven't specified what makes a distribution *good*. Is the distribution (1, 1, 1, 3) better or worse than (2, 2, 2, 0)? What about (3, 2, 2, 1)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback. I have edited the question. Hopefully the parameters are more well-defined now. Apologies for an initially ill-defined question.

Comment: What if there are three workers: two are available all week, and the third is not available at all. Does the work distribution still have to be $(10, 10, 10)$? Or should the work distribution be proportional to worker availability, so that  $(15, 15, 0)$ is the ideal? You *really* need to tell us what constitutes the goal here.

Comment: My apologies. I have amended the question to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Hm...I think there is a simple solution for this. Think of keeping some utility score.
If you are just concerned about weekly work allocation, consider this.

1. Before start of monday, set everyone's uility score to 0.

2.When work comes in, allocate work to any available worker with the lowest utility score. Recompute utility score, for that worker with the following formula:

utility score[new] = utility score[previous] + 1

3. Continue with Step 2 all the way to friday
4. Start from Step 1 again.

Does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had this solution in mind as well. But I'm unsure if it will result in as equal a distribution as possible on a weekly basis. Also, is it dependent on the amount of work coming in each day of the week being equal?